# JS bracket notation clarification

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

Thanks in advance. I have a concept question in JavaScript;

```
function rand(x,z)
  { return x + Math.floor((z-x+1)*Math.random()); }

function getLetter()
  { return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'][rand(0,5)]; }

console.log(getLetter());    // f  // a  // c  .....
```

I'm having trouble understanding how the `getLetter()` function logs a randomly selected letter just by returning two arrays. If I reverse the the array order it is logged in console as `undefined`.

Ultimately, I haven't seen this syntax before and it threw me off guard. Does the `getLetter()` function behave the same way as a `.map()` and `.filter()` approach?

Comment: There is no returning two arrays

Answer (score 2):

See the returned value as a row randomly picked up from an array:

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

like

```
Array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
  4 => 'e',
  5 => 'f'
)
```

The `[rand(0,5)]` is the row selector (random number from the first row id to the last row id, which are from 0 to 5).

Your `getLetter()` function can be seen as:

```
function getLetter() {
  var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  return letters[rand(0,5)];
}
```

Comment: This is a solid way of putting. Thank you!

Comment: No problem!! ;3

Answer (score 1):

`rand` returns a random integer between the two numbers passed in (inclusively-- `0` and `5` are valid returns, as are any integer in between).

`getLetter` leverages it as a means to get a random index in an array of letter that contains six letters.  So this:

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'][rand(0,5)]`

Calls `rand`.  And let's pretend it returns `2`.  So then we have:

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'][2]`

Which is the third item in the array, so 'c' is returned.

Answer (score 1):

There are no two arrays. There is one array and using bracket notation to reference an index in the array. Below is what the code basically does:

```
function getLetter() { 
   var options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],  //defined array
       randomNumber = rand(0,5),  //generate random number
       selection = options[randomNumber];  //reference index with the random number
    return selection;  //return the value
}
```

Comment: *face palm* Ah yes! Bracket notation! I feel a bit silly now since I'm in that habit of using `.` notation as an identifier. @anied @VHS @Matiboux your answers have helped me cement this idea and now I'm playing around with the different ways I can utilize bracket _and_ dot notation

Answer (score 0):

Your `getLetter` function is actually returning an element of a single dimension array. Basically it is creating an array of 6 characters (a thru f) and then returns the one pointed to by the index generated by the `rand` function.

The reverse (`return [rand(0,5)]['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];`) doesn't work because the array object generated in that case is a one element array (which contains a random number between 0 and 5).

Answer (score 0):

The `rand` function is just returning a number in the inclusive interval `[0, 5]`.

`getLetter` will just return the charcater in the `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` at the random character genered by `rand`.

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` is an array, `expression[x]` is on the other hand getting the element at the `x` index in the expression array **starting from zero**.